# How to stop or counter a timeout max pool size reached exception?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have set up a console .net core app (3.0.0 preview3) and have added a db context pool linked to my ef core model (2.2.4) and built the service provider

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
.AddDbContextPool<CorumClearDispenseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("Server=.;Database=*******;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
.BuildServiceProvider();
```

I then loop 10,000 times and make a request to the database

```
IEnumerable<DataLookup> searchData = null;

using (var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
           {
               var myDBContext = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<MyDBContext>();
               searchData = await myDBContext.DataLookup.Where(p => p.Description.Contains("test")).Skip(0).Take(100).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();

           }

return searchData ;
```

now while running this code I always get a timeout max pool size reached exception. For clarity, the database and console app are both on the same machine.

Could someone clarify that my understanding is correct when I say, by default I should have a pool size of 128 and that my requests are using them all and they are not finishing fast enough for the dbcontext to return to the pool by the time the next request is made?

I am also presuming my using code is correct and it will release the resource back to the pool once leaving the using?

What is the best approach to handle/mitigate this exception, is there any way of throttling the request until there is one available in pool?

Comment: You are definitely leaking connections. IOW the code is not correct. I don't know how to fix it though. Is this code really representative? Try disposing the context, not just the scope.

Comment: Hi @usr thank you for taking the time to comment. I tried without success unfortunately. I took my examples from [link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/14169) and [link](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10694) where I was led to believe when the scope is disposed, it will automatically dispose all instances resolved from it, so the disposing of the context is not required, in fact i thought it was best not to in this approach. Is this not the case then?

Comment: I have no idea because I'm not familiar with these particular APIs. You should still perform the experiment so that we can narrow down where the problem lies. Let's not just stare at the code but investigate. Please report back the results.

Comment: Hi, what did you come to? :)